# codesign error with xcode5.0.1 + mac os 10.9

Tags: xcode5, codesign, osx-mavericks

i just updated to mac os 10.9 and xcode 5.0.1, but codesign returned the error message"CSSM_SignData returned : 800108E6". no message with "exit code 1" and anything other. anyone has solution? thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I restarted my Mac and the same error (CSSM_SignData returned : 800108E6) is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It also happened to me recently, on Xcode 6.1.1. The error code shows inside the output of a Jenkins job. It turns out that one has to click "Always Allow" when code signing tool needs to load the certificate and asks user for permission. Since the jenkins job runs on a brand new Virtual Machine, no one has even started Xcode manually to file a build, the code signing tool probably waited for a long while, then errors out with this error code.

Comment: Don't think that this is Xcode version specific - but this fixed it on Xcode 7.3 as well: looking at the machine running jenkins, and clicking Always Allow when asked.The error I got was: User canceled the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting the DerivedData for the application.  That worked for me.